# How to break out of while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Why can't I break out of this loop in C?

```
        char command[1];
        scanf("%s", command);
        while(1){
                scanf("%s", command);
                if(command == "q")
                        break;
        }
```

Comment: Because it is laden with undefined behaviour.  You don't provide enough space in the string; you don't compare strings like that (use `strcmp()`).  You need to check the result of `scanf()`; it isn't clear that calling `scanf()` twice in a row is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want `%c` instead of `%s` in the scanf format. That will get you a single char. Then you can compare to "q" like this: `command[0]=='q'`.

But you might want to take in a multi-character command, in which case, strcmp and a longer buffer are what you want.

Answer (score 0):

'command' is a variable that contains address of block of memory somewhere in heap segment, while "q" is replaced by compiler with address of block of memory in the text segment,  where all constant strings are kept. That means the '==' operator compares two addresses in different segments of process memory.  Therefore it will never be TRUE. 
You have to use strcmp or strncmp function to compare strings and not addresses of these strings.